# Bash command substitution freeze

Tags: bash, qt, freeze, command-substitution

Currently I encountered the following situation when bash script freeze on

```
PID=`cat test.pid`
```

After the analysis it was found that even this commands freeze

```
TEST=$(echo 1)
TEST=`echo 1`
```

Using set -x in bash script, I can see the following output

```
+ echo 1
1
++ echo 1
```

for script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
echo 1
TEST=$(echo 1)
set +x
```

This script is called from Qt process and everything have worked lately.
When I call this script manually from bash it also works, but when I do it from process it fails.
Currently I'm looking for possible reasons of such freezes, and I've no more ideas.
When I printed environments they matched, but I also can't prinenv inside `` as it freezes also.

Comment: Could you post the calling code from your Qt program?

Comment: It is a bit difficult, there would be a lot of code. Qt code have not changed and it worked just on a previous week and it even works now on another linux server. In few words it is `QProcess` that sets working directory, environment and binds stdout/stderr and calls `start( m_str, QIODevice::ReadOnly )`.

Comment: Ok. What I would like to see is if you are calling bash from Qt or if you are passing your bash string.

Comment: @jbh, I pass `m_str = trUtf8("./script.sh")`

Comment: Have you make this script executable (chmod +x script.sh)? You could also look at process error status and errorString to help you debug this case

Comment: As you can see I set `chmod +x` as script has already started and froze during command substitution code. No error is produced and there is no exit status as script is still running.